# Java Client won't connect to remote server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server

Bare with me as it's been a while since I've been on here and I know there's format rules for questions. I have coded two java applications, both are pretty simple. One being a server and two being a client that connects to the server via socket. Now this works on my computer but when I have a buddy run on his computer it doesn't connect. I want the server to be able to run on my computer and anyone who has the client can connect.

The relevant code for the server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// write your code here
    System.out.println("Server Running...");
    int port = 1020, backlog = 5;
    String ipAddress = "2552:548:41aa:c3f0:563c:hgj9:8ca2:b3aa";
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, backlog, InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
    Server server = new Server(serverSocket);
    server.startServer();
}
```

The relevant code for the client:

```
public class Client{

public String username;
private Socket socket = new Socket("2552:548:41aa:c3f0:563c:hgj9:8ca2:b3aa", 1020);
public BufferedReader bufferedReader;
public BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
public ChatController chatController;

public Client(String username) throws IOException {
    try {
        this.username = username;
        this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bufferedWriter.write(username);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        listenForMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works on my computer but the not when client is on a different computer. My thoughts are that the issue is on the client side, possibly not using an open port? Thank you in advance and let me know if I need to edit if it's not a proper question format.

Comment: Do you have a static publicly accessible IP?  On your computer you probably run through a local server - but you cannot do it if a client runs somewhere else.

Comment: @PM77-1 I believe my IP address is publicly accessible.

Comment: You should not be providing an IP address for the server socket.  Your friend's system will not have any IP address matching the hardcoded value.

Comment: @JimGarrison you're talking about the socket in the Client class correct? He will be running the client on his end. I thought the serverSocket IP is the endpoint for the client socket to point to?

Comment: No, the socket on the server end.  Each server will have its own IP address(es), and hardcoding your server's IP will not work.

Comment: @JimGarrison it makes sense what you said. So for the serverSocket it should only take in a port parameter? That's what I did and my client won't connect to it when it's run on my local machine. I'm only going to be running one server on my computer so it should be my public ip.